# Headers are not working as expected in user profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, markdown

Header 3 (Sub-sub heading) are not working in user profile pages. This is present as `Header 3 ###` under Headers section in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). While typing the profile info, it is working and showing in the preview.

Pic 1:

[image: Cropped screenshot from profile page.]

When the information is saved, the sentence in the sub-subheading gets converted into normal characters.

Pic 2:

[image: Picture after saving]

Header 1 (#) and Header 2 (##) are also not showing up in bold after saving the profile.

I don't know since when this problem started. I found this an hour ago while I was trying to update my profile info using headers on Hinduism. I checked whether this is a site specific problem but this I faced the same problem here, Hinduism and Movies.

On a side note, pressing enter key twice only gives a line break. I think that should leave a line space between the heading and the paragraph. Right?

These are working fine on mobile web (tested on Android with Google Chrome browser) but not when we switch to full site.

Pic 3 on mobile version.

[image]