# Bold (**) not rendering correctly on Firefox

Tags: bug, design, markdown, firefox

Firefox Version 56.0 (64-bit) OS X

Here is the markup:

[image]

This is what it looks like in Chrome:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

Inspecting the element I can see that the output HTML is:

`<p><strong>Class.CaseTriggerHandler.execute: line 43</strong></p>`

And CSS has been applied:

```
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Although it's still not rendering correctly.

Comment: Sure it's not something on your side? Maybe some browser plugin/userscript you installed and forgot about? Try to disable everything and see if bold works.

Comment: 100% - Tried safe mode with add-ons disabled, same thing

Comment: Well, can't repro and surely if others could, meta sites would be swamped with bug reports. So let's hope a dev can somehow reproduce.

Comment: Is this only happening on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com?

Comment: That's a really good question... I just tested a bunch of sites and yes, it looks like it's only happening on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do note that different stacks often use different fonts, and font weights in browsers sometimes do not get handled properly if the font isn't "built correctly". Perhaps this is something to look into.

Comment: Related: [Italic/bold markdown on Code Review not working for some browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302082/323179).

Comment: mobile site or desktop site?

Comment: Desktop site. Mobile looks good

Comment: Strongly related - [Headers are not working as expected in user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301580/357396). I tried on Google chrome too but the headers are not showing bold in the profile page.

Comment: [Related issue](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/strong-formatting-broken/2666), nearly identical, except this impacts chrome.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? OP, are you still unable to see bold?